# Getting this error continuously: MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When I tried to log in, on my website. It responded with the message:

```
FatalErrorException in UserController.php line 37:
Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Auth' not found
```

But, the file there is controllers folder in Http containing Auth where there are four files.

UserController:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
//use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Flash;
use InvalidConfirmationCodeException;
use Flash;
//use Mail;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;
class UserController extends Controller
{

public function getDashboard()


   {

         return view('dashboard');
   }


 public function postSignUp(Request $request)
 {

    $email = $request['email'];
    $name = $request['name'];
    $password = bcrypt($request['password']);

    $user = new User();
    $user -> email = $email;
    $user -> name = $name;
    $user -> password = $password;

    Auth::login('$user');

    $user->save();

    return redirect()->route('dashboard')


 }

 public function postSignIn(Request $request)
 {

    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['email'], 'password' => $request['password']]))  {

        return redirect()->route('dashboard');
    }

           return redirect()->back();

 }
}
```

also, I am getting an error while signup:

```
MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:
```

And I am trying to solve this error from a very long time but no success till now. 
Please help me with both the errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change Auth::login($user)   -->  \Auth::login($user)
and let me know if you are getting anything in database after signup . :)

Comment: Yes i changed it. Thank you, and when I tried to sign up, i got another error: ErrorException in SessionGuard.php line 441:
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\lar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager.php on line 294 and defined

Comment: i'm currently in my college i will make sure your problem is solved in 4 hours . :) --> vishwas

Comment: ya sure: 
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function(){
 
 Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');

  });

 Route::post('/signup',[
  'uses' => 'UserController@postSignUp',
  'as' => 'signup'
 ]);

 Route::post('/signin',[
  'uses' => 'UserController@postSignIn',
  'as' => 'signin'
 ]);


 Route::get('/dashboard',[
   'uses' => 'UserController@getDashboard',
   'as' => 'dashboard'
 ]);
});

Comment: Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

            Route::post('/signup',[
                'uses' => 'UserController@postSignUp',
                'as'   => 'signup'


                ]);

            Route::post('/signin',[
                'uses' => 'UserController@postSignIn',
                'as'   => 'signin'


                ]);

            Route::get('/dashboard',[
                 'uses' => 'UserController@getDashboard',
                 'as'   => 'dashboard'
                ]);

Comment: paste this i want to see if you are getting same error

Comment: laravel 5.2 does not need much to do with middleware

Comment: thank you i did it, and now i an getting an error: ErrorException in SessionGuard.php line 441:
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\lar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager.php on line 294 and defined

Comment: i got the solution ...

you have not used "$" when you defined request

Comment: public function postSignIn(Request $request)
     {

        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request['email'], 'password' => $request['password']]))  {

            return redirect()->route('dashboard');
        }

               return redirect()->back();

     }

Comment: use this..public function

Comment: thank u .. but again same error :ErrorException in SessionGuard.php line 441:
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard::login() must implement interface Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, string given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\lar\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\AuthManager.php on line 294 and defined

Comment: i might have solved that problem, but now i am getting this error ... confused!

Comment: ok listen, open my stack profile and look up to my question "unable to sign in by lara"  we almost are using same code . :) . we have same code . look in my questions

Comment: you can check your error . my code is right no error was there in it .

Comment: It's funny. I checked my code. Yes, they were similar except certain things. I changed them and made them identical. Still same error : MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218

Comment: I don't understand what is the problem with it... If the code is same, then I should work, there might be a problem with my RoutesCollection.php file.. right? or anything else... i just can't figure it out.

Comment: Yes, my code worked. Thank you so much. Now i get it. I forgot to use some files. :)

Comment: The code was troubling me for a long time. Thank you so much for putting efforts and helpling me :)

Comment: Good . No Problem . you can always ask for my help :) ...just comment .....if you are satisfied with my answer please mark tick to my answer .. :)

Answer (score 0):

To get rid off

> FatalErrorException in UserController.php line 37: Class
>   'App\Http\Controllers\Auth' not found

Add `use Auth` at the top

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\User;
use Auth;
```

Comment: thank you,, did it.. but now it's giving me another error:

Comment: ErrorException in UserController.php line 39:
Use of undefined constant Request - assumed 'Request'

Answer (score 0):

1. Change `Auth::login($User)` to `\Auth::login($user)`, your `$user` variable is incorrect as well.
2. Check your signup route, is it doing a `POST` (most likely it is) and you're sending a `GET` request?

Comment: Thank you.. did it.. but now another error pops out: ErrorException in UserController.php line 41:
Use of undefined constant Request - assumed 'Request'

Answer (score 0):

You need add

```
use Auth;
```

to your Controller.

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt that the **Auth** class is inside your **Controllers** directory. The Auth you are looking for, is probably the Auth **facade**, can be included this way:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
```

Comment: thank you.. did it.. but now it's giving me an error:

Comment: ErrorException in UserController.php line 41:
Use of undefined constant Request - assumed 'Request'

Comment: You should also use the Request facade: use Illuminate\Http\Request

Comment: and I can see, there is an Auth directory inside controllers. Containing files: ForgetPasswordController, LoginController,RegisterController, ResetPasswordController. Then what's that?

Comment: That files are, as the structure indicates, Controllers. That is not the same as the Auth facade. The Auth Controllers are just predefined controllers for simple actions for Authentication, such as logging-in, registration etc. You could bind this controllers to your Routes, but it's optional, as you can write these Controllers yourself.

Comment: That is not true. Check the difference between these references.

Comment: It's in the second line, after declaration of namespace

Comment: And, when I get this error, and I refresh it, I am getting another error whose solution I am trying to find out from past 3 days. MethodNotAllowedHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 218:

Comment: Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function(){
 
 Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');

  });

 Route::post('/signup',[
  'uses' => 'UserController@postSignUp',
  'as' => 'signup'
 ]);

 Route::post('/signin',[
  'uses' => 'UserController@postSignIn',
  'as' => 'signin'
 ]);


 Route::get('/dashboard',[
   'uses' => 'UserController@getDashboard',
   'as' => 'dashboard'
 ]);
});